# Unable to create google play developer account due to google pay account suspension

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I am publishing my first app on google play console. I have sign up for google play developer account on google play console. I have followed the step one of submitting basic developer profile details. Second step is to pay the service fee of $25. In this step, I have entered my credit card number of my Visa card and click on buy. After this I have got an error message that

> Unable to accept the payment now. Your google pay account has been suspended. Learn more

When I have clicked on "Learn more", I have been asked to verify my account by proof of ID. I have uploaded my ID card and provided all the details required. On submission, they gave the message that

> Your Email has been sent. Thank you for contacting us

Now 3 days have been passed and I have not get any verification email from google, nor I am getting ahead from the payment form, to create a developer account.
Am I missing any thing, or am I doing something wrong?
Kindly help me to create my google play developer account.

Answer (score 0):

This could take time (at least a week), but if you want to make things go faster, try to contact customer support and use your passport instead of your ID to verify yourself, passport is accepted everywhere, but IDs of some countries is not accepted by Google.

Comment: What is a passport id?

Comment: Your travel passport